# Use Python to Lookup from a Power BI Table to another Table

Tags: python, powerbi, polygon

I am new to asking questions here so please forgive me if is not clear. I am also not an expert in Python but proficient in Power BI.

In Power BI, I have 2 columns in table A called Longitude and Latitude. In table B I have a column called WKT which has a Polygon of an area.

I need to check if the Long/Lat are inside the Polygon and if they do return a column in table A with the Polygon coordinate, and if they do not append the polygon coordinate at the bottom of Table A.

There is no function for this in Power BI, but there is one in Python called: isenclosedBy, from the library pygeodesy:

Something like the below:

```
if LatLon(TableA[lat], TableA[Long]).isenclosedBy(TableB[Polygon]):

    #New column in table A with Polygon
else:

    #Otherwise append the polygon at the end of Table A
```

The Polygon data is in Power BI in this format:

Polygon((-0.01 51.52, -0.02 52.03, -0.1 52.03,-0.01 51.52, -0.02 52.03, -0.1 52.03,-0.01 51.52, -0.02 52.03, -0.1 52.03,-0.01 51.52, -0.02 52.03, -0.1 52.03,-0.01 51.52, -0.02 52.03, -0.1 52.03,))

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Install python latest version using https://www.python.org/downloads/

In cmd, verify python installation using command ‘python –version’

Then install os, pandas, matplotlib, numpy using pip install.

import and load the required dataset in Powerbi Desktop. We can also create visualisation graphs and plots using python script. in visualisations tab, select python visual(PY) and select required fields from the dataset. a python script editor will be displayed.

First perform these steps in the Query Editor:

1. Select the 2 columns and change data type to whole number.
2. Add a custom column.
3. Expand to new rows and rename.
4. Convert back to dates.
5. Close and apply.
    
   then create this COLUMN in your Longitude table ( no relationship needed)

```html
POLYGON COLUMN =
LOOKUPVALUE (
    'Table A'[lat],
    'Table A'[Long], 'Table B'[WKT]
)
```

And then you will get the result.